# How to use ChartBuilder.setDataSourceUrl with Fusion Tables?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have that problem. When I set de URL of my request from my table in Fusion Tables, the chart does not work. It say 'Request timed out' when I play the App.

The code is:

```
var graficoHistoricoMensual=Charts.newAreaChart() .setDataSourceUrl('https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=select%20ANO,MES,%20count(INCIDENCIA)%20AS%20TotalIncidencias%20from ID_OF_THE_TABLEwhere%20ALMACEN=501%20group%20by%20ANO,MES%20&key=THE_KEY&alt=csv')
.setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0,1]))
.build();
```

When I executed this URL on one tab of the browser it work perfectly.

Does Fusion Tables work with Google App Script and this method of the Charts Services?

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried this, to answer you based on my experience, but from the error message it seems that Fusion Tables is just too slow for the Chart Service. Or, looking the other way, the Chart Service timeout is too low for Fusion Tables.

If that's really the case, you answer is no, you can not use fusion tables like this (using `setDataSourceUrl`).

But you can definitely use Fusion Tables data in Apps Script and pass to the Chart Services, you just need to grab the data yourself (using `UrlFetchApp`), parse it (using either `JSON.parse` or `Utilities.parseCsv`), and then create the charts datatable manually, `Charts.newDataTable`.